# How to filter second element in a tuple from a List in scala

Tags: scala

I have a List that contains data in tuple: (fileName, creationDate) which can be seen below.

```
latestFiles: List[(java.io.File, String)] = List(
(222651.log,2017-12-13), 
(222301.log,2017-12-11), 
(222305.log,2017-12-13), 
(222303.log,2017-12-12), 
(222302.log,2017-12-13),
```

The second element in the tuple denotes the creation date of the file (first element). 
I got the date in the form of the second element of the List by using below code.

```
val simpDate = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
val currDate = simpDate.format(new java.util.Date())
val now = Instant.now                                               // Gets current date in the format: 2017-12-13T09:40:29.920Z
val today = now.toEpochMilli
val t = (x:Long) => { new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(x)}
val todaySimpDate = t(today)                                        // Gets the date in the format: 2017-12-13
```

I need to go thru all the elements in the List:latestFiles and get the tuples that has the date as in 'todaySimpDate'.
I know there is 'filter' and SubList option to do that but I am unable to come up with a correct way. I tried the following way:

```
 val latefil = latestFiles.filter(y => (y._1,y._2==todaySimpDate))
 <console>:64: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (java.io.File, Boolean)
 required: Boolean
       val latefil = latestFiles.filter(y => (y._1,y._2==todaySimpDate))
```

I am not hardcoding the date value as I am getting the system date into a variable and then using it to compare the value.
I know that I am doing it the wrong way but can anyone tell me how to properly do it to get the elements from the List:latestFiles that contain second element in the tuple to the value present in "todaySimpDate".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your filter expression needs to return a bool, not a tuple

eg:

```
latestFiles.filter(y => y._2==todaySimpDate)
```

or:

```
latestFiles.filter(_._2 == todaySimpDate)
```